# The domain is not pointing to the application in tomcat, but instead points to the Ubuntu Default page

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee

When I type in my domain name in browser(example.com), it takes me to the Ubuntu's default page instead of taking me to the app. I have the following settings in server.xml

```
<Host name="example.com" debug="0" appBase="webapps/socialapp" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Context path="/socialapp" docBase="" debug="0" reloadable="false"/>
        <Alias>example.com</Alias>
        <Context path="" docBase="" privileged="true"/> 
         <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs/socialapp"
               prefix="socialapp_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
    </Host>
```

The A record in Hosting account points to the IP address and Cname has www and @ in it.
I want example.com to point to the webapps/socialapp folder of tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

i think this problem is occur because you don't set a welcome page in your app.
for do that edit your web.xml in your app like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>
```

add the above tag **over** all tags in web.xml file.this tag set index.jsp as your homepage of your app.

i hope this can help you.